# Confusion between array and pointer variable

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

we have

```
int a[2] = { 0, 1 } ; 
std::cout << &a ;
std::cout << a ;
```

Now when I run it, the output is the same for both!

Of what I have understood is that `a` decays to a pointer and gives me the address of the first element of the array i.e address of `a[0]`.

Which is similar to printing `std::cout << &a[0]`.

Now shouldn't `std::cout << &a` give me an error as `a` itself returns a pointer ?

Comment: No--the name of an array *usually* decays to a pointer--but *not* when used as the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the address-of operator (unary `&`).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `a` and `&a` have different types, but both are convertible to `void*`.

Comment: There is overloaded `operator<<` that takes `cout` and a `void *`. All object pointers can be converted to `void *`, so there is no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, regarding

> **”** `a` itself returns a pointer

No, the decay of array to pointer only happens in contexts where a pointer is expected. For example, it doesn't happen in a `sizeof` or `decltype` or `typeid` expression, or when the array is passed by reference to a function, or as here, when the address operator `&` is applied.

---

`&a` and `&a[0]` (or just `a` when decayed to pointer) refer to the same memory address, namely the first item of `a`, but have different types.

`&a` is a pointer to the whole array, and `&a + 1` therefore points to a second such array following the first.

`&a[0]` (or just decayed `a`) is a pointer to the first item, and `&a[0] + 1` therefore points to the second item.